# Is the term "Spans Unity" common?

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology, ideals

I recently saw a definition in a paper I haven't seen before. Given a commutative ring with identity $R$ and a subset $X$, we say $X$ spans unity in $R$ if there exist $a_1,...,a_n\in X$ and $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n\in R$ such that $1=\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i a_i$. It's easy to verify that this is equivalent to saying the ideal generated by $X$ is $R$. More generally, given another subset $Y$, we say $X$ spans unity in $R$ with coefficients from $Y$ if there exist $a_1,...,a_n\in X$ and $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n\in Y$ such that $1=\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i a_i$. Is this terminology common practice?

Comment: I don't know if it's common, but it's certainly reasonable given the linear-algebraic origins

Comment: I've seen the former property called "comaximal" as in "the set $X$ is comaximal (in $R$)". It is given as definition 2.1 [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.04832.pdf#page=53).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not seen this term before, and it gets [rather few hits on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22spans+unity%22), most of which appear to not be about math.  The more common term for this in my experience is "generates the unit ideal" (which gets [almost 20 times as many hits](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22generates+the+unit+ideal%22), almost all of which are relevant).

I don't know a more standard way to say "$X$ spans unity in $R$ with coefficients in $Y$", and the ability to neatly express this concept may be the reason that the authors chose to use the unusual terminology "spans unity".

Comment: Thank you for the information! Do you know if there is a more common way of saying "X spans unity in R with coefficients from Y"?